# How to mount local directory to remote hosts?

Tags: networking, nfs, centos-7, sshfs

I'm doing some experiments with some computers I have, I have the following scenario

```
local network
  host1 [ubuntu]
vps [internet]
  host2 [CentOS]
```

I have `an external hard disk` connected to the `host1` and my goal is to be able to access those files from the `host2`(VPS)

I can reach the host2 from the host1 over ssh but not backwards

```
host1 ---ssh--> host2 //possible
host1 <--ssh--- host2 //not possible
```

what I have done so far:

I tried using `sshfs` with reverse tunneling but I just can't have it work, I have seen lot's of examples where the connection is done from `host2` to `host1` but in my case since I can't ssh to host1 the samples I see don't work and there is very little info about reverse tunneling with `sshfs`

also, I tried with [mount-on](https://github.com/agirorn/mount-on) but it didn't work

is this possible under these conditions? if so, what am I missing?
is there something easier?

thank you

Comment: You say you can reach host1 from host2 but not reverse. You really need to fix this before trying to get NFS working.  What about setting up a VPN from host 2 to host1, then connecting over that? It's more secure for NFS as well.

Comment: yes, that is a problem, actually, right now I'm trying to set up a network tunnel between those hosts, I will give it a try and update :)

Answer (score 4):

is late but... maybe other can use this.

If you want to connect the remote server to your local computer, make a tunnel with ssh.

`$ ssh -NR 6969:localhost:22 my-ssh-key`

Then you have a connection on the remote server in port 6969 to your local machine. Now just type this code to connect your local directory to the remote server.

`$ sshfs -p 6969 YOUR_USER@localhost:/LOCAL_DIRECTORY/ /YOUR_REMOTE_MOUNT_POINT/`

Answer (score 0):

after struggling, for a couple of hours, I found out that there is no way to solve the issue without having bidirectional communication, so, what I did was to set up a VPN to have communication from the host2 to host1.

The full detailed procedure that I followed is available [here](https://donhk.wordpress.com/2018/04/04/custom-plex-setup/) hope it helps you if you are trying to accomplish something similar